# Combining array and literals for text label to fill table rows

Tags: arrays, string, ios7, append, string-literals

I am using the array "allscores" to parse the text label "scorelbl" in the populated table rows.

```
cell.scorelbl.text = [allscores objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] - 1];
```

This prints in the table rows

```
1
2
3
2
etc
```

I need now to add some literals next to each object of the array to make it print

```
1/5
2/5
3/5
2/5
etc
```

I know how to do this in a string, but I am looking for an easy way to integrate it to my existing line with the array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<[allscores count]; i++) {
  NSString* string = [allscores objectAtIndex:i];
  NSString * scorestringformatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/5", string];

  [allscores replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:scorestringformatted];
}
```

I am trying this out but it prints:

```
1/5
2/5/5
3/5/5/5
2/5/5/5/5
etc
```